# Determining whether a readable file descriptor is the read end of a pipe

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor, splice, zero-copy

I would like to use [`splice`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/splice) to zero-copy data from `STDIN_FILENO` to a file descriptor (which could be to a regular file, char or block device, FIFO, or anything that can be opened with [`open`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html)). In order to use `splice`, either the *from* file descriptor or *to* file descriptor must be the appropriate end of a pipe, so generally a pipe is created to serve as an intermediary buffer when the programmer wants to zero-copy data from non-pipe to non-pipe. However, if `STDIN_FILENO` is already the read end of a pipe, then I could skip that step and attempt to splice directly from `STDIN_FILENO` to the other file descriptor. Therefore, I would like to be able to determine whether `STDIN_FILENO` is the read end of a pipe.

Is there a Linux system call that can determine whether `STDIN_FILENO` is the read end of a pipe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get information about an open fd, you can use fstat(). I'd guess that st_mode of the result should be S_IFIFO for a pipe. Alternatively, /proc/self/fd/ and /proc/self/fdinfo/ also provide some information about a file descriptor. Keep in mind that /proc is linux-specific.

However, I think it might be easier to just try to use splice() first and if it fails (with EINVAL?) fall back to your magic.

Comment: I coded up a test program that created a pipe, called `fstat`, and tested `S_ISFIFO`: http://pastebin.com/ntauU2b5 . The result is that `S_ISFIFO` on the `st_mode` for the read end of a pipe is TRUE. Your guess is correct, and it is actually per the POSIX standard: "S_ISFIFO(m) Test for a pipe **or** FIFO special file" (http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, `lseek()` will fail with `ESPIPE` if "fd is associated with a pipe, socket, or FIFO." So a no-op `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR)` will tell you if the file descriptor is any of these.

In my situation, this covers all of the cases I was interested in.